# Proof that $|x|+|y|\leq\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: inequality

How do I prove that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $|x|+|y|\leq\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}$?

I thought that $(|x|+|y|)^2=x^2+y^2+2|x||y|\leq2(x^2+y^2)$, but I'm not sure why that holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim immediately follows from
$$\bigl(|x|+|y|\bigr)^2\leq\bigl(|x|+|y|\bigr)^2+\bigl(|x|-|y|\bigr)^2=2\bigl(|x|^2+|y|^2\bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

So what you're trying to prove is
$$
x^2+y^2\ge 2|x||y|
$$
which is the famous [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). You can prove it by completing the square.
$$
x^2+y^2-2|x||y|=(|x|-|y|)^2\ge0
$$

Comment: Im not sure how this proves my inequality

Comment: Subtract $(x^2+y^2
)$ from both sides of your last inequality. Do you see it now?

Answer (score 1):

By [the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), we have:

$$\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{(1+1)\left(|x|^2+|y|^2\right)}\geq|x|+|y|.$$

The CS inequality is the last step, applied with $(|x|,|y|)$ and $(1,1)$. Inequality says the scalar product is at most as great as the product of the norms:

$$|x|+|y|=(|x|,|y|)\cdot(1,1)\leq\|(|x|,|y|)\|\|(1,1)\|=\sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2}\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{(|x|^2+|y|^2)(1+1)}.$$

Comment: what is 'C-S' ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/572187)

Comment: @Mr.Fantastic C-S is probably Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Ramiro in fact it does answer. But I agree it is perhaps a bit too terse on explanations. Editing it in a moment.

Comment: Yes. As the answer  was originally presented, it was just restating the question just replacing $2$ by $1+1$. It is too terse, even for a hint. Now it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

The key is recognizing that $|x|^2 = x^2 \,\,\,\, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, and that the inequality you start with can simply be squared since both sides are guaranteed to be positive:

$$|x| + |y| \leq \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x^2 + 2 |x| |y| + y^2 \leq 2x^2 + 2y^2$$

The rest is rearrangement and factoring as shown by others.